# Error in reading email messages through javamail application

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to read email content and print the content through my java application. But its shooting no initial content exception error. kindly do guide.

I took this as a sample example code (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/fwfiy.html) and tried running it.

```
    final String username = "username";
    final String password = "username"; 

    InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
    String snName = "java:comp/env/mail/MyMailSession";
    Session session = (javax.mail.Session)ic.lookup(snName);

    Properties props = session.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.from", "abc@xyz.com");

    Store store = session.getStore();
    store.connect("smtpmail.de.xyz.com", username, password);

    Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();

    for (Message message : messages) {
        System.out.println(message.getDescription());
    }
}}

Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at EmailToString.main(EmailToString.java:23)
```

Comment: Are you running in an application server and have you configure the MyMailSession environment variable? If not, try the simpler [JavaMail sample programs](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/tree/master/demo/src/main/java).

Comment: Thank you for the message. I am using the sample program msgshow with the following changes.

Comment: What "following changes"?  Did you forget to include something in your post?

Comment: helllo Bill, thanks for your comments somehow the remaining part of the comments has disappeared. But i sorted the issue out, your code was pretty helpful. Thanks